# Issue in WebView Android History When update Chrome stable version 63

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

My Android app `webview` works fine with chrome version 61 or 62, but when I update to version 63. My `webview`does not store the history and `webView.canGoBack()` always returns `false`. But previous versions of chrome work fine. How to solve?

Answer (score 2):

This issue should be chromium's bug. We find out the  same issue in our apps. the reason of this issue is we invoke Webview's loadUrl methond in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, when we do that , webview can't go back in some version of chromium. The code below is my workaround:

```
public class WebViewBugFixDemo extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // todo : set your content layout

        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final String indexUrl = "http://www.yourhost.com";
        final String indexHost = Uri.parse(indexUrl).getHost();
        webView.loadUrl(indexUrl);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (isSameWithIndexHost(url, indexHost)) {
                    return false;
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && request != null && request.getUrl() != null) {
                    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                    if (isSameWithIndexHost(url, indexHost)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * if the loadUrl's host is same with your index page's host, DON'T LOAD THE URL YOURSELF !
     * @param loadUrl the new url to be loaded
     * @param indexHost Index page's host
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isSameWithIndexHost(String loadUrl, String indexHost) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(loadUrl)) {
            return false ;
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(loadUrl) ;
        Log.e("", "### uri " + uri) ;
        return uri != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(uri.getHost()) ? uri.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(indexHost) : false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is related to this [BUG](http://crbug.com/794020) I think.
Workaround works, confirmed.

Used to add additional headers with `loadUrl()`. 
Can't do that with this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue. For now You can use intent in ouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){} function and super.onbackpressed() will do its job to maintain history.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("postUrl", url);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: In my case creates new intents endlessly.