# webView.canGoBack() not working anymore

Tags: android, webview, onbackpressed

Recently all of my `WebView` based apps started to have problem with back button. It looks an issue with update of some Android Component, Kindly help with the issue or some alternative solution?

`webView.canGoBack()` always returning ***false***.

PS: All apps were working fine in previous days.

I'm using it like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have also noticed this. Check out [Chromium BUG 794020](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794020) and also [stackoverflow question 47771494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771494).

Comment: Exactly, hope they will fix it asap in an update.

Answer (score 1):

Create own canGoBack by like this....

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add(www.google.com);

//after that you need override this method
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+url);
            urls.add(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

//for onBackPressed, same like in custom button for back click option
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!canGoBack()
    {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//Custome Method
public boolean canGoBack()
{
    if(urls.size() == 1) // home page
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        webView.loadUrl(urls.get(urls.size()-2)); // load previous url
        urls.remove(urls.size()-1); // remove last loaded url
        return true;
    }
}
```